# maximal ideals of $C((0,1))$

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

For any compact set $\mathbb{K}$, set of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{K} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have all the maximal ideals of form $M_{\gamma}=\{ f: f(\gamma)=0\}$ for some $\gamma \in K$.

The problem is to show for $C((0,1))$, there exists infinitely many maximal ideals which are not of the form $M_{\gamma}$, for some $\gamma \in (0,1)$.
 Also, I want to ask, does it have any connection with compactification of (0,1)?

Please help me with this.

Comment: I suppose you mean $x_n\to 0$ instead of $\frac12$?

Comment: Well, as to your idea, how would that fail to work in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$, if your sequence converges to $\frac{1}{2}$? Perhaps think about what kind of continuous functions you might have defined on $(0,1)$ that you wouldn't be able to use in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$.

Comment: If $M$ is a maximal ideal, then $C((0,1))/M$ is a field.  But I think (for cases other than $M_\gamma$) it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, instead some giant extension field of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Another hint: do you know any maximal ideal on $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R})$ that is not of the form $M_x$? Or at least, an ideal that, while not maximal, is necessarily contained in a maximal ideal that cannot possibly be of the form $M_x$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin, Thanks a lot, I am trying to figure out something.

Comment: To ping someone, don't link to their user page. Use the `@username` format. Though it only works for someone who has participated in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The set $M$ you describe is an ideal, but need not be maximal. However, it must be contained in some maximal ideal $\tilde M$. We want to achieve that $\tilde M$ is not of the form $M_\gamma$. Unfortunately, we have $f(\frac12)=0$ for all $f\in M$ (because $f$ is continuous), hence certainly $M\subset M_{\frac12}$ and so possibly $\tilde M= M_{\frac12}$. However, if you adjust your definition and replace $\frac12$ with $0$ (or $1$), then $\tilde M$ cannot be equal to any $M_\gamma$ because we readily find $f\in M$ with $f(\gamma)\ne 0$.

But how do we find infinitely many *different* maximal ideals? By picking different sequences $x_n\to 0$, of course!
Note that any $f\in C((0,1))$ with $f(x_n)\ne 0$ for all $x_n$ is $\notin \tilde M$: 
Let $g(x)=\min\{\,|x-x_n|:n\in \Bbb N\,\}$. Then $g\in M$ and $f^2+g>0$, so that from  $f\cdot\frac f{f^2+g}=1-g$, we conclude $f\notin \tilde M$.

Hence by using pairwise disjoint sequences converging to $0$, we obtain pairwise distinct maximal ideals because we can easily find continuous functions (similar to $g$ above) that are zero on the one sequence but nowhere zero on the other sequence and vice versa.
Concretely, we find continuum-many such sequences by letting $x_n=\frac1{n+c}$ with a parameter $0<c\le 1$.

Comment: Yes, for my construction, it is becoming $M_{\frac{1}{2}}$. But if I take $\{x_{n}\}$ and $\{y_{n}\}$ disjoint, then it is giving the maximal ideal, $M'_{0}=\{f: lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=0\}$.

Comment: This $M'_{0}$ is not even ideal..